# Filter data on call to getHyperCubeData

Tags: qliksense

When I run the following, I got all records from my table object (assuming i have 100 records in all).  Is there a way to send the selection/filter, for example, I want to retrieve only those where department='procuring'.

```
    table.getHyperCubeData('/qHyperCubeDef', [{
        qWidth: 8,
        qHeight: 100
    }]).then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I don't understand why people keep voting down my question without explanation.  For me it's a valid question and I have come up with an answer after doing more research and reading.  I am very new to Qlik Sense fyi.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the answer. Before getting the hypercube data, I need to get the field from the Doc class, then do the following:

```
.then(doc => doc.getField('department'))
.then(field => field.clear().then(() => field.select({qMatch: filter['procuring']})))
```